# Getting AlreadyExistsException error while trying to create/update bash script for Cloudformation

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cloudformation

HI Am trying to write a bash for quickly creating/updating new stack for my deployment creation works fine but for the same when I try to update the stack am getting below error
*An error occurred (AlreadyExistsException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Stack [Test-stack] already exists*

BASH script below

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

usage="Usage: $(basename "$0") region stack-name [aws-cli-opts]
where:
  region       - the AWS region
  stack-name   - the stack name
  aws-cli-opts - extra options passed directly to create-stack/update-stack
"

if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ] || [ "$1" == "help" ] || [ "$1" == "usage" ] ; then
  echo "$usage"
  exit -1
fi

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ] || [ -z "$3" ] ; then
  echo "$usage"
  exit -1
fi

shopt -s failglob
set -eu -o pipefail

echo "Checking if stack exists ..."

if ! aws cloudformation describe-stacks --region $1 --stack-name $2 ; then

  echo -e "\nStack does not exist, creating ..."
  aws cloudformation create-stack \
    --region $1 \
    --stack-name $2 \
    ${@:3}

  echo "Waiting for stack to be created ..."
  aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete \
    --region $1 \
    --stack-name $2 \

else

  echo -e "\nStack exists, attempting update ..."

  set +e
  update_output=$( aws cloudformation update-stack \
    --region $1 \
    --stack-name $2 \
    ${@:3}  2>&1)
  status=$?
  set -e

  echo "$update_output"

  if [ $status -ne 0 ] ; then

    # Don't fail for no-op update
    if [[ $update_output == *"ValidationError"* && $update_output == *"No updates"* ]] ; then
      echo -e "\nFinished create/update - no updates to be performed"
      exit 0
    else
      exit $status
    fi

  fi

  echo "Waiting for stack update to complete ..."
  aws cloudformation wait stack-update-complete \
    --region $1 \
    --stack-name $2 \

fi

echo "Finished create/update successfully!"
```

Comment: Do you have the IAM permissions to do it? If you run it natively does it work? I tested and when I did not have the permission it triggers to hit the create statement

Comment: Yes i have and the create-stack works fine, only when I modify the CF to update the stack getting the error, here is how I am running it.
./createUpdate.sh Test-stack --template-body file:///home//aws_deploy_stack/sample.yaml --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM

Comment: The IAM permissions would be for `describe-stacks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error seems to be able to trigger when I do not have permissions for the `describe-stacks` function. Check your permissions to run this.

By not having permissions it enters the create stack logic.

Comment: So there will be separate set of permissions for aws cloudformation create-stack and describe-stacks ? 
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name Test-stack
is returning with this message
Unknown output type: yaml

Comment: Have you got the default output in your CLI config as yaml rather than json? If you're on CLI v1 you won't have support for YAML which would cause it to error and always return the first statement :)

Comment: Thanks Chris! yes CLI seems to be the problem. Now resolved.

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)